# Will, Can, Present Simple

Tags: grammar

A portion of the information is generated to guarantee the error free provision of the website. Other data MAY BE USED to analyse your user patterns.

What does the sentence mean with MAY BE USED? What would it mean with CAN BE USED, WILL BE USED, IS USED?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the website providers reserve the right to use your data, generally for the purpose of placing advertisements relevant to you on the site.

Answer (score 0):

- MAY be used = they have permission to use it
- CAN be used = they have
  the ability to use it
- WILL be used = they have the will or the
  intention to use it
- IS used = they regularly use it

"Can" is often also used for permission, but "may" is preferred in formal contexts.

"May" can sometimes be used for possibility, but it is likely that "might" would be used for this purpose for the purpose of clarity in a legal context.